# How do i get powershell to check if my computer's Windows update are more than 30 days out of date

Tags: powershell, windows-update

I'm testing if my computer's windows updates are more than over 30 days old and pop up a message to warn the user if they are.

Can someone please help me with the testing of the date, as it just seems to give me the same result of `YOUR WINDOWS UPDATES ARE IN DATE` no matter what.

I think i need to change the format of the date to be able to test it against the `Get-Date` result?

```
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_reliabilityRecords -filter "sourcename = 'Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
    select -first 1 @{LABEL = "date"; EXPRESSION = {$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.timegenerated)}}, @{LABEL = 'Update'; EXPRESSION = {$_.message}} |
    FT -AutoSize -Wrap

$DateTimeNow = Get-Date
$Daysback = "-31" 
$Updatedate = $_.ConvertToDateTime

if ($DateTimeNow.AddDays($Daysback) -lt $Updatedate.InstalledOn.Date) {
    $wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell

    $wshell.Popup("***WARNING***YOUR WINDOWS UPDATES ARE OVER A MONTH OUT OF 
    DATE. PLEASE CONTACT  IT", 0, " Windows Update Check", 0x1)
}
else {
    $wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell

    $wshell.Popup("YOUR WINDOWS UPDATES ARE IN DATE", 0, " Windows 
    Update Check", 0x1)
}
```

Comment: Why not this? `gwmi win32_quickfixengineering |?{ ($_.Installedon -gt ((Get-Date).adddays(-30))) -and ($_.Installedon -lt (Get-Date))}`

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
$LastUpdate = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_reliabilityRecords -filter "sourcename = 
    'Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Select -first 1 @{LABEL = "date";EXPRESSION = {$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.timegenerated)}},@{LABEL = 'Update';EXPRESSION = {$_.message}}

$DateTimeNow = Get-Date
$Daysback = -31

if($LastUpdate.Date -lt $DateTimeNow.AddDays($Daysback)){
    $wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
    $wshell.Popup("***WARNING***YOUR WINDOWS UPDATES ARE OVER A MONTH OUT OF DATE. PLEASE CONTACT  IT",0," Windows Update Check",0x1)
} else {
    $wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
    $wshell.Popup("YOUR WINDOWS UPDATES ARE IN DATE",0," Windows Update Check",0x1)
}
```

**Changes:**

- You weren't returning the result of the `Get-WmiObject` call to a variable and were then testing `$Updatedate` which was always empty.
- Your date logic needed to be reversed.